# Add up all numbers from richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have a `richtextbox` with specific numbers in each line, and I want to add up all the numbers. It works for now but it only allows up to 4 rows. if I have more then 4 rows in `richtextbox3.text` I get an `overflowexception unhandled error`. It works fine if `richtextbox3.text` is 4 or below.

```
    Dim strLines() As String
    Dim lngLoop As Long
    Dim lngvalue As Long
    Dim lngTotal As Long
    strLines = Split(RichTextBox3.Text, vbCrLf)
    lngTotal = 0
    For lngLoop = LBound(strLines) To UBound(strLines)
        lngvalue = Val(strLines(lngLoop))
        lngTotal = lngTotal + lngvalue
    Next
    Dim stringArray As String() = RichTextBox3.Text.Split(ControlChars.Lf)

    Dim sum As Double = 0
    For Each element As String In stringArray
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(element)
    Next




//RichTextbox3.text  
  2000
  1000
  3000
  1000
  4000
```

Comment: Try this : RichTextBox3.Text.Split(New Char() {vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your split doesn't actually work since the line break sometimes uses different characters.

Just try using the Lines property from the RichTextBox control:

```
Dim sum As Integer = 0
For Each s As String In RichTextBox3.Lines
  Dim num As Integer = 0
  If Integer.TryParse(s, num) Then
    sum += num
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, 
It working like a charm now.

Comment: @Cubuz : Remember to mark Lars's post as the accepted answer by pressing the green tick on it's left.